# Dates in Character to actual Dates using R

Tags: r, date

I have dates in the format:"5/8/1971 0:00:00"   "5/8/1971 0:00:00"   "5/8/1971 0:00:00" . Its in character format.
I have tried as.Date(), as.numeric(as.character()), as.POSIXct(), as.Date.POSIXct(). I am getting two different results either the dates are replaced by "NAs" or getting error "character string is not in a standard unambiguous format". All is done using R
Share your thoughts, please.

Comment: Is this month first?

Comment: `as.POSIXct("5/8/1971 0:00:00", format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")`. This returns a datetime object, to have only the date, `as.Date(result)`.

Comment: @RuiBarradas Thank you for guidance, This does the job.

Answer (score 2):

The `anydate()` function in the `anytime` package can help:

```
> library(anytime)
> anydate(c("5/8/1971 0:00:00", "5/8/1971 0:00:00", "5/8/1971 0:00:00"))
[1] "1971-05-08" "1971-05-08" "1971-05-08"
>
```

If you prefer POSIXct, the `anytime()` function can create those:

```
> ## also for datetime objects if you want those
> anytime(c("5/8/1971 0:00:00", "5/8/1971 0:00:00", "5/8/1971 0:00:00"))
[1] "1971-05-08 CDT" "1971-05-08 CDT" "1971-05-08 CDT"
>
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use

```
library(lubridate)
mdy_hms(dates)
```